# Gibbs free energy of transition and activation energy

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics, transition-state-theory

Let's consider a reaction A (reactant) -> B(product) and [activated complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activated_complex) is denoted by C.

[image]

This graph ( potential energy vs reaction coordinate ) tells us that reactant need some amount of activation energy (Ea) to convert in product, which has low potential energy which is shown here in terms of enthalpy ∆H. We can assume from this graph that activation represent same kind of potential energy between A (reactant) and C (activated complex ) that Enthalpy ∆H represent between A and B (product).

Now look at another graph of reaction (Gibbs free energy vs extent of reaction)

[image]

This graph represents that activation energy is difference between Gibbs free energy of reactant and activated complex or there is also possibility that the activation energy shown here is not arrhenius [activation energy Ea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_energy) but it is Gibbs energy of activation ΔG‡ according to [transition state theory.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_state_theory)

---

**Q.** **But to perform a reaction what amount of energy we need to supply to reactants arrhenius activation energy Ea or gibbs free energy of activation ΔG‡ ?** I think it's ΔG‡ as defination of Gibbs free energy states - minimum amount of work needed to supply for a non spontaneous reaction (here A -> C ) to be happened but then why arrhenius theory states that - for reactants to transform into products, they must first acquire a minimum amount of energy, called the activation energy Ea ?

**And also what these two energies represent *physically* in terms of bonds , interatomic interactions etc ?**

[Mathematical equations](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Kinetics/06%3A_Modeling_Reaction_Kinetics/6.02%3A_Temperature_Dependence_of_Reaction_Rates/6.2.03%3A_The_Arrhenius_Law/6.2.3.03%3A_The_Arrhenius_Law-_Activation_Energies) -

ΔG‡ = ∆H‡ - T∆S‡

ΔG‡ = Ea - RT - T∆S‡   ( ∆H‡ = Ea - RT )

---

Comment: Here are two sources ([oxford lecture notes](http://vallance.chem.ox.ac.uk/pdfs/TSTnotes.pdf) and [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Statistical_Thermodynamics_and_Rate_Theories/Eyring_Transition_State_Theory#Example)) to look into this topic further than the Libretext source cited in the question.

Comment: It is possible that you are mixing several concepts that are related but are not identical. $\mathrm{E_a}$ stems from the Arrhenius equation that describes the dependence of k(T) with temperature. $\mathrm{E_a}$  is an empirical parameter. ...

Comment: (cont.) However, for a simple reaction profile that presents a barrier between reactants and products, Fowler and  Guggenheim showed that $\mathrm{E_a}$ roghtly corresponds to difference be the average energy of the molecules that react and the average energy of the reactant molecules (see K. J. Laidler, Chemical Kinetics, Pearson,1987). ...

Comment: (cont.) The thermodynamic formulation of the TST allows you to express k(T) as a function of the "thermodynamic" magnitudes that you can estimate through theoretical calculations or experimental data. Be aware that the mathematical expressions that relate $\mathrm{\Delta G^‡}$, $\mathrm{\Delta H^‡}$ and $\mathrm{\Delta S^‡}$ are obtained when you compare the TST expression with the Arrhenius equation. $\mathrm{E_a}$ and $\mathrm{A}$ do not appear as part of the TST theory.

Comment: @PAEP To perform a reaction what amount of energy we need to supply to reactants arrhenius activation energy Ea or gibbs free energy of activation ΔG‡ ?

Comment: @Karsten the link you have provided (Oxford lecture notes) is not working

Comment: @Bharat Prajapat your question is answered in the reference we  have given you. I think that unless you understand what you are asking your question does not make much sense.

Comment: By the way you can access Clare Vallance lecture notes through the link provided by @Karsten. I checked it today and yesterday. It is a link to a pdf file, so you need a pdf reader.

Comment: @PAEP "However, Ea roghtly corresponds to difference be the average energy of the molecules that react and the average energy of the reactant molecules ". That average energy is what - 1. Internal energy  2. Gibbs free energy or 3. Enthalpy

Comment: Guess it is not so simple. You should review your Statistical Thermodynamics and  what is the meaning of the $\mathrm{\Delta U^‡}$, $\mathrm{\Delta H^‡}$,  $\mathrm{\Delta S^‡}$  and $\mathrm{\Delta G^‡}$.

Comment: @PAEP I know about each term that's why I am asking that when fowler and guggenheim derived expression for average energy change between reactant and  product molecules,  in which form of energy (  ΔU‡, ΔH‡ and ΔG‡  ) they calculated average energy.

Comment: Please note that the activated complex model is outdated and superseded by transition state theory.

Comment: To obtain the Fowler and Gugghenheim expression you do not refer to Thermodynamic parameters. It simply did not make sense to partition the energy change in $\mathrm{ΔU^‡}$, $\mathrm{ΔH^‡}$, $\mathrm{ΔS^‡}$ or $\mathrm{ΔG^‡}$. It is well explained in Laidler's books which is a textbook (old but very insightful).

Comment: I think you are overstretching the capabilities of the Thermodynamic Formulation of the TST. As @Martin points, it has been superseeded by later more evolved formulations of the theory (btw, some of them described in Laidler´s textbook).

Comment: Well yes, sure, there are more evolved models after TST, but I actually wasn't referring to that. One needs to understand TST, especially its shortcomings,before understanding anything further. But you don't need to understand AC to understand TST.