# Thermodynamics potential and differences between them

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, chemical-potential

There are 5 most common [thermodynamics potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_potential#:%7E:text=It%20is%20the%20energy%20of,from%20an%20expression%20for%20U.) -

[image]

But we will discuss about only three of them -

- [Internal energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_energy) (∆U)
- [Enthalpy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy)(∆H)
- [Gibbs free energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_free_energy) (∆G)

As Gibbs free energy is also a thermodynamics potential that means it is not related to only energy of bonds and [interatomic interactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interatomic_potential) but also to [entropy potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_entropy).

---

**1. So now my first question is that** **what thermodynamics potential actually represent physically not mathmatically?**

---

Now talk about those three thermodynamics potential -

I find it most confusing that how internal energy , enthalpy and Gibbs free energy are different form of energies or potential although looking at the mathmatical expressions we can easily say Gibbs free energy is different from   enthalpy by a additional term -TS or enthalpy is different from internal energy as it has a additional term pV. But how they are different form of energies theoretically?

Let's consider a example of chemical reaction to understand what I am actually asking.

[image: potential energy vs reaction coordinate]

This is most common diagram used in our textbooks which shows  potential energy of system when reactant is converting into product. but the difference of potential energy between reactant and product is ∆U or ∆H or ∆G ? And how  these 3 terms (∆U,∆H,∆G) ***physically*** represent 3 different kind of potential energies  between reactant and product ?

**Physically** means in terms of bond energies, interatomic forces and  interactions , molecular kinetic energy , vibrational energy, rotational energy etc.

Ok finally I address my question in more clarified language - internal energy of a system (here reactants and products) as per it's  defination includes all kinds of kinetic and potential energies of system so when we say there is difference between reactant's and product's internal energy by ∆U , we have included all kind of energy differences between reactant and product. but when we say there is a difference ∆H between enthalpy ( or ∆G between Gibbs free energy ) of reactant and product , does it represent any **specific type of potential energy in internal energy** difference between reactant and product means ***does ∆H ( or ∆G) is a specific part of internal energy?***

Comment: H and F are used under different conditions and automatically account for any pV work.  G was invented because, experimentally the limiting amount of work that could be obtained in reactions was not described by $\Delta H$.  Gibbs first realised that in a reaction heat could be taken from or given to surroundings (via entropy) and so work done is different to that predicted by $\Delta H$. In your picture  potential is not defined, but probably U is meant, but could be energy just in the bonds that break.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the term state function is more common that the thermodynamic  potential, while both are correct.

Considering $U$, $H$, $F$ and $G$ as different forms of energy may be misleading.

The state function **internal energy** $\ce{U}$ is intuitively well understood as the total system kinetic and potential energy. Formally, the energy E=mc^2 should be included to, but as the interest is usually in $U$ changes, it is not involved, being many orders higher than the rest.

The state function **enthalpy** $H = U + pV$ (as pV is a state function too) is not other form of energy, but made up state function. At isobaric conditions, enthalpy change is energy added to the system that is used

- to increse the system internal energy
- to do mechanical volume work on the neighbourhood, due volume changes.

For thermally induced system expansion:

$$\mathrm{d}H = \delta Q - \delta W = C_V \mathrm{d}T + p\mathrm{d}V = C_V \mathrm{d}T + p \left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_p \mathrm{d}T \\ 
= \left(C_V  + p \left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_p \right)\mathrm{d}T = C_p \mathrm{d}T$$

$\Delta H - \Delta U$ may be formally considered as energy, that system does not store in form its internal energy, but lends/borrows it to/from its neighbourhood via mechanical work.

**(Free) Gibbs energy (or "free enthalpy)**  $G = H -TS = U + pV - TS$ is not other form of energy either, but yet another made up state function. It is the maximal part of enthalpy, that is, at least theoretically, available to do work, allowed by the 2nd law of thermodynamic.

For reversible isothermal and isobaric process, $-\frac{\Delta G_\text{sys}}{T} = \Delta S_\text{sys} + \Delta S_\text{surr}$

Imagine 2 almost identical, isolated systems:

- The system A contains 2 thermally connected identical metal blocks at equilibrium, at $\pu{T = 300 K}$ and temperature independent heat capacity.
- The system B is identical to the system A, but the blocks have the temperature respectively $\pu{290 K}$ and $\pu{310 K}$.

Both systems have the same internal energy and enthalpy. But the system A has higher entropy $S$ and lower Gibbs energy $G$. The difference is the part of the thermal energy of the blocks that can be used to do some work, e.g. via thermal engines or thermocouples generating electricity.

Note that the part of the thermal energy available to do work has the same form as the part of the thermal energy not available to do work. The difference is in quantity, not quality.

Comment: in the question 18 , here  https://books.google.co.in/books/content?id=2eWe_lUQP9IC&pg=PA178&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&bul=1&sig=ACfU3U0D2XpDwUvrdR5o5d6vf7Xyr3NSFQ&w=1280         author writes that enthalpy is that energy of system which is available  for conversion  in heat but then how can enthalpy be greater than internal enery. as expression of enthalpy has a additional  pv term

Comment: When you isobarically heat up the system, part of heat is used by system doing expansion work. the added enthalpy is then bigger than added internal energy. The reverse path converts compression work done on system to the extra heat, so the enthalpy 
(absolute) change is again bigger than internal energy change. It can be effectively said that the part of enthalpy that is not internal energy is stored remotely, out of the system, as external energy.

Comment: whenever I use word internal energy of system, the thing comes in my mind is total energy of system including  kinetic + potential but when you say enthalpy of system what comes in your mind that which property of system  you are talking about  ?

Comment: As above....... //  Or by other, analogy way:   Internal energy = local hard disk.  Enthalpy = local hard disk + cloud storage.  (do not consider their ratio, just qualitatively] Then not all data go to the local disk and not all data come from the local disk.  The data stored as enthalpy are not stored in the local disk by different way. They are stored there by usual way or are not stored there at all, but elsewhere.

Comment: By yet other words, the difference between Delta H and Delta U relates to energy interchange between the system and the neighbourhood  behind your back, as W = - p. Delta V..

Comment: last comment - I found a question https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/175332/129242 although it is not related to what i have asked , but if you answer this question I think that will solve all my doubts regarding Different  types  of energies and their physical significance .

Answer (score 0):

So the change in energy, indeed is a mixture of kinetic and potential energies as you said.
The difference with the free energies in general is that they give you an idea of what the direction of the reaction is going to be (towards the lower $\Delta G$ or $\Delta\mu$ etc.).
This is a very general explanation which gives an idea of what is happening. Of course, many things can happen since the entropy and enthalpy also have to be taken into account.

The difference between all the free energies is dependent on how you define your system (or what it's characteristics are).

Comment: in the question 18 , here  https://books.google.co.in/books/content?id=2eWe_lUQP9IC&pg=PA178&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&bul=1&sig=ACfU3U0D2XpDwUvrdR5o5d6vf7Xyr3NSFQ&w=1280         author writes that enthalpy is that energy of system which is available  for conversion  in heat but then how can enthalpy be greater than internal enery. as expression of enthalpy has a additional  pv term

Comment: I wasn't able to access the question, but about what the author wrote, don't forget that energy can be taken from many places like breaking bonds, or from irradiation or maybe, by changing the pressure or volume of the system which comes into account by the PV term.

Comment: last comment - I found a question  chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/175332/129242 
 although it is not related to what i have asked , but if you answer this question I think that will solve all my doubts regarding Different types of energies and their physical significance .